# How to make a QML Item completely block input events to other Items underneath it?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Suppose I have an `Item` (in this example a `Rectangle`) covering another `Item` (in this case a `WebEngineView` with a `PinchHandler` inside). How do I make sure that the `Rectangle` blocks all user inputs (including mouse, touch, hover, wheel, keys, etc.) to the `WebEngineView`?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtWebEngine 1.0

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    WebEngineView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        url: "https://www.google.com/maps"

        PinchHandler {
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: console.log("active changed", active)
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    }
}
```

I have tried setting a `MouseArea` and `MultiPointTouchArea` to the `Rectangle` to block mouse and touch events respectively:

```
Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: Qt.rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        acceptedButtons: Qt.AllButtons //to block right click and middle click
        hoverEnabled: true //to block hover events
        propagateComposedEvents: false
        onWheel: wheel.accepted = true //to block wheel events
    }

    MultiPointTouchArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

However, the `PinchHandler` inside the `WebEngineView` still gets activated by pinch events. How do I make the `Rectangle` eat up all events and prevent any items and input handlers underneath from becoming activated?

Comment: for mouseEvent's simply you can add a mouseArea fill to the upper rectangle and accept all mouse events like clicked or pressed...

Comment: @SajadBlog yes i have already done that as mentioned in the question. But i also want to filter out all events including touch, wheel, keys etc.